# Using the RequireJS text plugin

Tags: javascript, text, requirejs, karma-runner

I am using Karma to run tests against some code.

Both the tests and the code are transpiled (ES6 => ES5 using babel) before being run by Karma.

This works great and the tests run fine.

But if I try and use the `text!` plugin from any of the files being tested...

```
import template from 'text!./template.html';
```

...I get:

```
There is no timestamp for /base/src/text.js!
Uncaught Error: Script error for "text", needed by: text!app/template.html_unnormalized2
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror 
Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules: text!app/template.html_unnormalized2
```

Does anyone have any ideas why this might be?

The built artifact in the `dist` folder (i.e. the item under test) contains the successfully encoded text RequireJS items eg:

```
define('text!app/template.html',[],function () { return '<div>foo</div>';});
```

---

**Additional Info**

**test-main.js**

```
var TEST_REGEXP = /(spec|test)\.js$/i;
var allTestFiles = [];   
Object.keys(window.__karma__.files).forEach(function(file) {
  if (TEST_REGEXP.test(file)) {
    var normalizedTestModule = file.replace(/^\/base\/|\.js$/g, '');
    allTestFiles.push(normalizedTestModule);
  }
});

require.config({
  baseUrl: '/base/src',
  paths: {},    
  shim: {},
  deps: allTestFiles,
  callback: window.__karma__.start
});
```

**karma.conf.js**

```
module.exports = function(config) {
    'use strict';    
    var path = require('path');    
    var cdn = 'http://localhost:55635/modules/';
    var basePath = path.dirname(__filename);

    config.set({
        basePath: '../../..',
        frameworks: [
            'requirejs', 
            'jasmine'
        ],
        files: [
            {
                pattern: path.join(basePath, 'test-transpiled', '*-spec.js'),
                included: false
            },
            path.join(basePath, 'dist', 'artifacts', 'app.js'),
            path.join(basePath, 'test', 'unit', 'test-main.js')
        ],
        proxies: {
            '/cdn/': cdn
        },
        exclude: [],
        preprocessors: {},
        reporters: ['dots'],
        colors: true,
        autoWatch: false,
        singleRun: false,
        browsers: ['Chrome'],
    });
};
```

**Edit:**

I have added the following to karma.conf.js:

```
files: [
  {
    pattern: path.join(basePath, 'node_modules/require-plugins/text/text.js'),
    included: false
  },
   // ...
],
```

I continue to get an error when running the tests:

```
There is no timestamp for /base/src/text.js!
```

Presumably because I need to add "text" to the paths section of test-main.js?

```
require.config({
  baseUrl: '/base/src',
  paths: {
    'text': '../node_modules/require-plugins/text/text'
  },
  // ...
});
```

But I have tried various combinations of `baseUrl` and the path in the `text` path and I cannot get it to stop 404-ing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `files` option in `karma.conf.js` does not include the `text` plugin, which is why you get the error that there's no timestamp for it.

Add an item to your `files` list that hits the `text` plugin on your file system, and make sure that you have `included: false` for it. RequireJS plugins are like other modules: RequireJS must be able to load them to use them.

You may need to also set `paths` in `test-main.js` depending on where you put your plugin. RequireJS already is looking for it at `/base/src/text.js`. If you locate it so that the plugin is served at this URL, then there's no need to set `paths`. If you put it somewhere else, then you do need to set `paths`. Something like:

```
paths: {
  text: 'path/to/text',
}
```

Remember that the paths in `paths` are interpreted relative to your `baseUrl` setting.

Comment: Do I need to add an item to `paths` in `test-main.js` too? ( `'text': '...'` )

Comment: The plugin resides in `node_modules/require-plugins/text/text.js`. I am unsure how to refer to this successfully from within the test-main however. Everything I have tried 404s.

Comment: When running karma the module is available at `http://localhost:9876/basesandbox/dev/app/node_modules/require-plugins/text/text.js` (verified using the browser). But I do not know how to get require (or karma) to look there for it. My application code resides under `/c/sandbox/dev/app`. Unsure if this contributes to the `basesandbox/dev/` bit of the above URL.

Comment: You should try with an absolute path `text: '/basesandbox/dev/app/node_modules/requi‌​re-plugins/text/text‌'` and see if it solves the issue. Sometimes it is hard to picture how the various parts mesh together.

Comment: It works with the hard-coded absolute path. Suspect this will break on other machines - eg build machines, so I would love to know how to use relative pathing.

Comment: In order to use the absolute pathing, I need to send information on how to construct the path to `test-main.js`. Is there a communication path (probably in settings) that I can leverage for this?

Answer (score 0):

I tried using the require.js text! plugin, and also found that it conflicts with the baseUrl defined for the rest of the project.

The requirejs.config sets the baseUrl to the parent directory of the JS files, while my templates are defined in a sibling directory to the js.
 There was no way to tell requirejs to load templates from /base/templates and js from base/js.

My solution was to change the text.js plugin, and add a hook to change the url just before the ajax call is made to fetch the HTML file. You can take my version of text.js from [here](https://github.com/YishTish/text).